# ActiveRecord Search Facet Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 with postgres. Let's say I have a Book model that can be filtered by type and tag. I'm curious how to implement facet count for each filter (type, tag, ...) to display in the search result. The ui would look something similar to this:

```
Book Type
Banking(30)
IT(20)

Tags
business(20)
rspec(2)
rails(3)
```

I've been googled trying to find way to do without using Sphinx, Solr or any other search engine. Can it be done by postgres or activerecord?

Answer (score 2):

```
type_facet = Book.select('type, count(*)').where(:type => ["Banking","IT"]).group(:type)
tag_facet = Book.select('tag, count(*)').where(:tag => ["business","rspec","rails"]).group(:tag)
```

Iterate over the above facets in your frontend..

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this?

```
Book Type
Banking (<%= Book.where(:type => "Banking").count %>)
IT (<%= Book.where(:type => "IT").count %>)

Tags
business (<%= Book.where(:tag => "business").count %>)
rspec (<%= Book.where(:tag => "rspec").count %>)
rails (<%= Book.where(:tag => "rails").count %>)
```

Comment: it gonna slow down if I have more filters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Book.count(:all, :group => 'type')
Book.count(:all, :group => 'tag')
```

I think it will returns the count and each type/tag for you.